# Configuring Log4j2 with JVM argument, no error but the log files aren't logged properly

Tags: java, jvm, log4j, log4j2, jvm-arguments

I am using Log4j2 to log several files which some of them are based on `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` and others are on `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` all defined in a `log4j2.xml`. It worked all well until wanted to have the configuration done in the tomcat server.

I added `-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=<pathToLog4j2.xml>` in my JVM arguments. It still creates the log files but the rotation rules are totally ignored and some of the logs are with no content.

What am I missing here to make it work with the configuration in Tomcat Server?

Comment: Check [this question](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1258). My guess is that you are deploying multiple copies of `log4j-core` that struggle to rotate the same files at around the same time.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thank you, it was indeed this. And instead I decided to add a copy approach in the server to rewrite the log4j2 configuration for one specific server that I need this config.